# ExpressJS Get resulting source from view instead of rendering it

Tags: node.js, express, railway.js

I'm intending to use some ejs templates to generate HTML for sending out emails.

I'd like to pass in a model to my view, and get back the resulting HTML
So, instead of render() - i want to 'get' the html into a variable before it's passed back to the browser?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following will work:

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var str = ejs.render("<title><%= title %></title>", {title: 'Hello'});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: thanks... can i specify a path to the view instead of the actual value of the template..?

Comment: You could use the fs package to load your .ejs straight from the file system